# Alicloud:How to get regions/zones where cluster can be created?

Tags: alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs

Not all regions supports the creation of managed kubernetes clusters.

Which API calls let me discover regions in which kubernetes clusters can be created?

Answer (score 0):

[Developer Guide for **Alibaba Cloud Container Service for Kubernetes**](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/90776.htm) doesn't have any API for getting the regions in which Kubernetes clusters can be created.

However, you can have a look at the following link, which shows all the availability of the product based on region. **Alibaba Cloud Product Regions (International and China):**
https://www.alibabacloud.com/global-locations#floor2

Screenshot (International Product Region):
[image]

Screenshot (China Product Region):
[image]

List of all the current available regions in Alibaba Cloud:
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/40654.htm
[image]

You can get updates on release notes of Alibaba Cloud Container Services of Kubernetes on the following link:
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/98310.htm